# setContentOffset to start at the bottom of scrollview not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

Hi guys I’m a total newbie in Xcode, i have this view controller that has a scrollView of height 2000. I want that when it loads, it starts at the bottom of the scrollView.

I have read that setContentOffset should help me with this but i just can’t make it work. I don’t know what I’m doing work. Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks,

```
import UIKit

class Pantalla2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let off = CGPointMake(0, 2000)

    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(off, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Your viewcontroller's view might not have been loaded yet in `viewDidLoad()`, try moving the `setContentOffset` line of code to `viewDidAppear()`

Comment: hi @Zhang i tried that but not working...  
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) { 
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, max(scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height, 0) ), animated: true)
    }

Comment: ScrollView Height must not be greater than screen size . you should try to use view inside scrollview with height 2000 pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
!

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

     self.scrollview.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 2000)

}
```

Comment: question about contentOffset not contentSize

Comment: Sorry for ContentSize code  ! This new code  works for me

Comment: are you using auto layout, then move this code into viewWillLayoutSubviews

Comment: Hi guys. @karthikeyan, im not using auto layout, is just a main view > scroll view > view > 3 images

Comment: how are you setting up scrollview and where are you setting contentSize to scrollview? can you print your scrollview object and update log details here

Comment: Thanks @karthikeyan it seems i wasn't setting the contentSize, its working now!